# Inconsistent results during debugging - Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have some code that uses a library for a product called Fusion Pro. Based on some config and data files it will generate a PDF file. I have been getting consistent result of a complete lack of output without any thrown exceptions. However when debugging I have been able to get the PDF to generate by attaching the debugger to the code running in my local IIS and stepping through line by line. Nothing is consistent though. It seems to have a higher success rate if I use F11 instead of F10 and going "slow but steady" through each line. Unfortunately it doesn't always produce a PDF even with stepping through the code.

I have never experienced code behaving so inconstantly with the same inputs each time.

The only other relevant bits of information is this code is working in another asmx service without issue, it is running under a specific domain account (requires special security), and it is running in 32bit mode.

```
DLQueueClient client = new DLQueueClient();
DLQueueJob vdpQueueJob = new DLQueueJob();

string fileName = message.OutputFilePath;

var dataFilePath = CreateDataFile(fileName, message.DefFilePath, message.VariableDataContent, message.QTY);
var pdfFilePath = Path.Combine(new[] { message.OutputFilePath, dataFilePath.Replace(".txt", ".pdf") });

vdpQueueJob.Priority = priority;
vdpQueueJob.Queue = queueName;
string cmd = "\"" + Settings.FusionProExe + "\" \"" + dataFilePath + "\" \""
                          + message.DiffFilePath + "\" \"" +
                          (isProof ? message.ProofConfigFilePath : message.PrintConfigFilePath) + "\" \""
                          + pdfFilePath + "\"";

vdpQueueJob.CommandLine = cmd;

client.ConnectRemote(Settings.FusionProServer, Settings.FusionProUser, Settings.FusionProPassword, Settings.FusionProTimeout);
client.SubmitJob(vdpQueueJob, Settings.FusionProTimeout, true);

return pdfFilePath;
```

Comment: Is it possible there are some job timeouts involved?

Comment: There is a timeout passed in when you connect to the job server. It has the same value as the other functioning service does so I had not tried to tweak it at all. I could try to adjust it a little bit and see what happens.

Comment: Why the visual studio 2012 tag was removed. It felt relevant as it was the environment this was developed in and I had seen some other questions in the past where the environment or debug mode made a difference. If not relevant I can not tag it in the future. Just curious.